# codeigniter pagination for search not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

here controller calls search function and performs pagination. I am getting output but the pagination for search results is not working because when I click forwardlink of pagination it works but when i click back link of pagination it will show the information of database but not the searched information. I am just new at codeigniter i don't know what to do.

Controller (main.php)

```
    public function search()
    {
      if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
      {  $this->load->model('model_users');

         $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "main/search";
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->model_users->get_count();
    $config["per_page"] = 2;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $config['next_link'] = '&gt;';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&lt;';


    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
     //  $data['offset_no'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $match = $this->input->post('search');
    $data["results"] = $this->model_users->
        get_search($config["per_page"], $page, $match);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

   $this->load->view('search', $data);
      }
      else
      {
        redirect('main/restricted');
      }
   }
```

model(model_users.php)

```
    public function get_search($limit, $start, $match)
   {
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);


    $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('users');
   $this->db->like('name',$match, 'before');
    $this->db->or_like('address',$match, 'before');
    $this->db->or_like('email',$match, 'before');
    $query = $this->db->get();

  if($query->num_rows() > 0)
  {

    foreach($query->result() as $row)
  {
     $data[]= $row;
  }
     return $data;
     }
     else return False;
     }

      public function get_count()
     {

        $match = $this->input->post('search');
                             $this->db->select('*');
             $this->db->from('users');
           $this->db->like('name',$match, 'before');
            $this->db->or_like('address',$match, 'before');
          $this->db->or_like('email',$match, 'before');
           $query = $this->db->get();


             return count($query->result());





     }
```

view : search.php

```
           <div class="search">
       <?=form_open('main/search');?>
        <?php $search = array(
          'name'=>'search',
         'id' => 'search',

         'style'       => 'height:25px',
        'style'       => 'align:center',
         'value'       => $this->input->post('search')
         );
               ?>
                  <?=form_input($search);?><input type=submit value='Search' /></p>
          <?=form_close();?>

            </div>
         <?php
                 if($results)  {

           echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <th> USER_ID  </th>
         <th> USER_NAME</th>
              <th> EMAIL</th>

        <th> USER_ADDRESS</th>
          <th> CONTACT_NO</th>
        <tr> ";
     foreach($results as $row){
       echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" .$row->id. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row->name. "</td>";
     echo "<td>" .$row->email. "</td>";
       echo "<td>" .$row->address. "</td>";
      echo "<td>" .$row->contact_no. "</td>";


         echo"</tr>";
         }
           echo"</table>";
            }
         else
       {
        echo "No results was found in the table for
       this keyword " .$this->input->post('search');  }             








              ?>
                     <p><?php echo $links; ?></p>
```

Comment: What error you are getting? please var_dump your error here.

Comment: hey, I am not getting any error , I get search results but pagination for that search results is not working... when i click next pagelink then it will not load searched information of database rather all info of database come in next link. there is problem in linking of pagination i think so.

Comment: Inspect element and Check the href second link generating, might not been calling valid controller/method.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
<thead>
   <tr>
    <th>#</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>###</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```